# Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments for line-22

Tags: apex, entitlements

I have the workflow, which updates the field `Case: On Hold Time` when status=On Hold changes to any other value.

```
PRIORVALUE(On_Hold_Time__c)+ NOW()- DATETIMEVALUE(On_Hold_Start_Time__c)
```

where

```
1) On_Hold_Time__c   Number(12, 6)
2) On_Hold_Start_Time__c Date/Time
```

The same formula looking to implement using the trigger logic, but getting the below error.

> Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments for line-22

Here is the trigger logic

```
Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Case c : newCases){
    if(c.Status == 'On Hold'){
        caseIds.add(c.Id);
    }
    else if(c.Status != 'On Hold'){
        caseIds.add(c.Id);
    }
}

List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id, IsStopped, Status FROM Case WHERE Id IN :caseIds];

List<Case> lstCase = new List<Case>();
for(Case ca : cases){
    Case c = new Case(Id = ca.Id);                
    if(ca.Status == 'On Hold'){
        c.IsStopped = true;
        c.On_Hold_Start_Time__c = System.now();
    }
    else if(ca.Status != 'On Hold'){
        c.IsStopped = false;
        c.On_Hold_Time__c = (ca.On_Hold_Time__c + System.now()) - ca.On_Hold_Start_Time__c; //line-22
    }  
    lstCase.add(c);
}
update lstCase;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, leverage `Stopped Since` (API name `StopStartDate`) attribute of Case object when you are making `isStopped=true`. This will return when the case is stopped calculating milestones.

> Arithmetic expression works on number, so first convert datetime to seconds and then calculate the difference.

Replace the line 22 with this:

```
c.On_Hold_Time__c = ca.On_Hold_Time__c 
           + Integer.valueOf((System.now().getTime() - ca.StopStartDate.getTime())/1000);
```

`On_Hold_Time__c` will store values in seconds.

Be sure to first query `StopStartDate` in SOQL.

Comment: Thanks. As per workflow formula, this should add first PRIORVALUE(On_Hold_Time__c)+ NOW() and then DATETIMEVALUE(On_Hold_Start_Time__c) should be subtracted ?

Comment: ultimately result will be same, you cannot calculate the difference of datetime based on Arithmetic expression.